# How does the Lord's discipline (falling asleep)exempt them from being finally condemned with the world in 1 Corinthians 11:32?

Tags: 1-corinthians, pauline-epistles

Paul admonishes the Corinthians for abusing the Lord's supper.

> **1 Corinthians 11:29[NIV]** For those who eat and drink without discerning the body of Christ eat and ***drink judgment on themselves***.

He goes on to say that many are sick, weak and some have even fallen asleep(dead) because of this.

> **1 Corinthians 11:30[NIV]** That is why many among you are weak and sick, and a number of you have ***fallen asleep***. 31 But if we were more discerning with regard to ourselves, we would not come under such judgment.

Finally, he says this is God's discipline so that they will not be condemned with the world

> **1 Corinthians 11:32 NIV** Nevertheless, when we are judged in this way by the Lord, ***we are being disciplined so that we will not be finally condemned with the world***.

Now my question is how does this discipline of falling asleep(death) exempt them from being condemned with the world?

Comment: @Dottard Not in the slightest. I suggest you post an answer and validate your opinion, sir, rather than 'shout' at people (using capitals).

Comment: Good question. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1):

The question makes several assumptions about 1 Cor 11:29-32 that are non-sequiturs:

1. The Lord's discipline is death or falling asleep.  The passage does not say this nor is it implied.
2. Falling asleep (death) somehow exempts people from final divine condemnation.  Again, the passage does not say this, nor it it implied.

What the passage does say appears to be the following:

- V28 - Each must examine himself
- V29 - Those who eat and drink without recognizing the body and blood of Christ invite judgment on themselves
- V30 - This has caused some be weak and sick and even die
- V31 - If we judged ourselves properly (Rom 12:3 - Do not think of yourself more highly than you ought ...) we would have avoided such a problem
- V32 - when judged by the Lord, we are being disciplined (to make us better people, see Heb 12:6 - the Lord disciplines the one he loves, and he chastens everyone he accepts as his son) and thus we will not be condemned by the world.

Note the important distinction make by Paul here about the three different judgements going on:

**Judgement #1** - judgement by oneself, V28 & V29 & V31a

**Judgement #2** - judgement by God, V29b & V32a

**Judgement #3** - judgement by the world, V32b

Therefore, Paul is presenting the regular communion service as a time of self reflection to ensure that we eat and drink with due humility and recognition of our sinful condition and great need of Christ.  Such will make us avoid the pitfalls of pride, self sufficiency, arrogance, and most importantly, how much Christ has done for us and how much we need Him.

There is a great promise in this passage that we also read in John 5:24 -

> Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word and believes Him who
> sent Me has eternal life and will not come under judgment. Indeed, he
> has crossed over from death to life.

Finally, death does not excuse anyone from judgement because we also read in John 5:28, 29 -

> Do not be amazed at this, for the hour is coming when all who are in
> their graves will hear His voice and come out—those who have done good
> to the resurrection of life, and those who have done evil to the
> resurrection of judgment.

Note that there will be a class of people who, having died will be raised at the general resurrection to receive judgement (BSB) or condemnation (NIV).